# > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.7. gradle error and other similar errors in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, groovy

I have invalidated caches and restarted deleted .gradle files, nothing seems to work

I keep on getting this error whenever I build using release variant
It works fine while using debug version
I currently have no dependencies that weren't set for me

I'd be eternally grateful if I could get a solution, that doesn't involve suppressing lint
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.7.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/3.0.7/groovy-all-3.0.7.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.32.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.4.32/kotlin-reflect-1.4.32.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadata sources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.32.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.4.32/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.32.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.0.1
   > Could not find org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.0.1
   > Could not find com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.1
   > Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:30.0.1
   > Could not find com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.10.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.10.0/protobuf-java-3.10.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:4.1.0-alpha01-6193524
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:30.0.1
   > Could not find javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
   > Could not find net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/intellij/deps/trove4j/1.0.20181211/trove4j-1.0.20181211.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:30.0.1
   > Could not find xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.12.0/xercesImpl-2.12.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.20/commons-compress-1.20.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdklib:30.0.1
   > Could not find commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/7.0/asm-tree-7.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/7.0/asm-commons-7.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-util:7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/7.0/asm-util-7.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
   > Could not find it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:8.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/8.4.0/fastutil-8.4.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
   > Could not find net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
   > Could not find com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
   > Could not find com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1
   > Could not find com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.1
   > Could not find com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:repository:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.0.1
   > Could not find net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.6.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.6.0/jna-platform-5.6.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:30.0.1
   > Could not find com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.0.1
   > Could not find com.google.guava:guava:30.1-jre.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/30.1-jre/guava-30.1-jre.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:7.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.0.1
   > Could not find commons-io:commons-io:2.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.0.1
   > Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:30.0.1

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added `mavenCentral` to the `allProjects` repository and it worked.